# не работает PastSpecial

Tags: vba

Нужно скопировать нужный диапазон и вставить его в ВОРД без таблицы, как обычный текст с заданным форматом текста. Но работает только нижний текст с прописанным ".Past" . По разному пробовал написать ".PastSpecial" но выдает Debug. Где ошибка?

```
`Sub Word()

       Dim objWord

       Dim objDoc

       Dim objSelection
    '-------------------------------------------------
       Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

       Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

       objWord.Visible = True

       Set objSelection = objWord.Selection


        Range("B51:B60").Copy

        With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
               'All formatting goes here
            .Paste
            .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            .Font.Color = black
            .Font.Size = 11

        End With

        objDoc.SaveAs ("D:\MyFirstSave")


    End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно будет подключить (Tools -> References) `Microsoft Word *.* Object Library`

```
Sub ExportValueFromTable()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document

    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add

    wApp.Visible = False

    Range("A1:A7").Copy

    wApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText

    With wDoc.Range
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Color = Black
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With

    wApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```